# Undefined entry script in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking at the docs for process

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

I see this:

> process.mainModule
>
> ## Added in: v0.1.17
>
> Alternate way to retrieve require.main. The difference is that if the
>   main module changes at runtime, require.main might still refer to the
>   original main module in modules that were required before the change
>   occurred. Generally it's safe to assume that the two refer to the same
>   module.
>
> **As with require.main, it will be undefined if there was no entry script.**

Under what circumstances would you have a running node.js program with no entry script?

Comment: Example of circumstances where entry script is undefined - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3072

Comment: Commit in Node 6.2.1 where this issues was fixed - https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/6902/files